# How to make a property accessible on all screens using conductor?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a `ListBox` on a Window. This Window's model uses Caliburn with a conductor:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
```

My screens are user controls (each UC has a Model) that gets loaded when I click a tab on `TabControl`.

I want to be able to access the `ListBox` selected item on all my screens.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I can use `EventAggreagator`

In my `AppBootstraper` class I can add:

```
private CompositionContainer _container;
```

And under the `Config` method:

```
var batch = new CompositionBatch();

batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
batch.AddExportedValue(_container);

_container.Compose(batch);
```

In my main ViewModel's constructor:

```
IEventAggregator eventAggregator
```

And in the bound property:

```
public Thing SelectedThing
{
    get { return _selectedThing; }
    set
    {
        _selectedThing = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedThing);

        _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(SelectedThing);
    }
}
```

Then on my screen models:

```
public class MyScreenViewModel : Screen, IHandle<Thing>
```

In the constructor:

```
IEventAggregator eventAggregator
```

Then:

```
_eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
_eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
```

Interface implementation:

```
void IHandle<Thing>.Handle(Thing selectedThing)
{
    this.SelectedThing = selectedThing;
}
```

More about it: [Caliburn Micro Part 4: The Event Aggregator](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/01/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/)

Answer (score 0):

The other option (although more coupled) is to use  the fact that Screens have a "Parent" property which you can use to access their conductor; so you could do something like the following in the MyScreenViewModel.

```
void GetSelectedThing()
{
var conductingVM= this.Parent as ShellViewModel ;
this.SelectedThing = conductingVM.SelectedThing;
}
```